# Sending data to external database

Tags: ip

I would like to send the data from a form response to an external database that is already set up and on the Internet (Microsoft Azure platform) with an IP number. I have the log in information and everything.  Has anybody done anything like this?

Comment: Yes.  Get access to the server.  Make sure you can write to it remotely (which is unlikely).

Comment: Yes, people have done this before.

Answer (score 0):

It's all equal to a connection to `localhost`. Only parameters, obviously, change.

Maybe you have an address like this:

```
mysql://[user]:[password]@eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com/[database_name]?reconnect=true
```

Use the various parts to get data to use with the language of your choice.

Here there are some examples in various languages: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-quick-start-client-code-samples/